# Create new instance on every user request

Tags: javascript, performance, express, request, instance

Performance question - I'm trying to understand if i have a node http server powered by express , is it consider bad practice to create new class instance on every request sent by the user? 
The class instance fetch data from another api and expose some functionality to manipulate the fetched data.

example of the code:

```js
        //--- Handler.js ---
        const _ = require("lodash");

        class Handler {

            constructor() {
                this.fetchData = this.getSiteModel.bind(this);
                this.getA = this.getA.bind(this);
                this.getB = this.getB.bind(this);
                this.getC = this.getC.bind(this);
            }
            
            async fetchData(req,res,id){
              const result = await fetch(...)
              this.data = result;
            }  

            getA(){
            ...
            return this.data.A
            }
            
            getB(){
            ...
              return this.data.B
            }
            
            getC(){
            ...
              return this.data.C
            }
    }

    //---- controller.js ----
    const Handler = require("../Handler/");
    
    exports.getDataById = async function(req ,res) {
         const handler = new Handler();
         return handler.getA();
    }
```

Would it be better to do this instead

```js
        //---- controller.js ----
        const fetchData = require("../Handler/");
        const getA = require("../Handler/getA");
        const getB = require("../Handler/getB");
        const getC = require("../Handler/getC");

        exports.getDataById = async function(req ,res) {
              //no new handler instance created
             const data = fetchData(url)
             return getA(data);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it considered bad practice to create new class instance on every request sent by the user?

No, it's not generically considered a bad practice.  It's normal to need to create objects during the processing of an incoming request.  Look at any database query which is often used during a request handler.  It will likely create multiple objects.

Now, whether or not there is a more efficient way to do what you're doing is a different question and we would need to see your actual code in order to offer some advice on that topic.

> Would it be better to do this instead?

I don't see a whole lot of reasons for you to put the data into an object before making a single operation on that object.

Something like you proposed (with the addition of `await` to make it work properly):

```
   exports.getDataById = async function(req ,res) {
          //no new handler instance created
         const data = await fetchData(url)
         return getA(data);
    }
```

Seems perfectly fine to me.  When to structure things into a class and put the data into the instance data and why to just use a function to operate on the data is a classic OOP question and it depends upon lots of things which are all dependent upon seeing and understanding your real code, what you're doing with it, how it is most likely to be expanded in the future, how often you are calling multiple functions on the same data in one request, etc...

Comment: is it better to just import those functions instead of having create the object? the import will be just once and i don't really see the point of creating a new instance if the only state i'm holding is just the data fetching from 3rd party api for the specific request.

Comment: @Tomer - It doesn't matter how many methods there are in the class.  Those are just referenced from the prototype and don't add anything to the weight of creating an object.  This is one of the advantages of a prototype-based language.  What would matter more is are you spending time initializing a general purpose object in ways that are not used at all.  I really don't want to speculate any more on that topic.  The way it works here is if you want specific and pointed feedback on your code, you include your code IN the question.

Comment: @Tomer - FYI, Reusing an object in multiple places is good design.  Building a house, when you just need a mailbox would obviously be wasteful.  So, it depends upon the specific code and operation in the request.

Comment: But isn't creating and deleting an object is considered a very expensive action?

Comment: @Tomer - Not really unless the constructor does a lot of unnecessary housekeeping.  Every time you call a string method, you're creating a new string object.  Javascript lives by objects. You can't really do much without creating lots of objects.

Comment: @Tomer - The whole class you added to the question seems a little extraneous to me.  I'm not sure what value it's offering unless you're leaving out lots of other code that contain the actual value.  A single function can just fetch the data, return the object in a promise and let the caller get whatever piece of that data they want out of it.  But, none of this is going to matter to the performance of your application.  Nothing you show is going to be material one way or the other.  My comments about what you've shown so far are just comments about the code design, not about performance.

Comment: @Tomer - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community, by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and also earn yourself some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.